# Виды сайтов для front-end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css3, html5

Какие виды сайтов может создать front-end разработчик с нуля без помощи бэкенда ? Спасибо вам

Comment: Сейчас уже любые виды - благодаря развитию таких технологий как WS, WebGL, Filesystem API, а также облачным serverless функциям (при исп. SaaS, что тоже бэкэнд но "другой"), и т.д..

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой: лендинг (в народе сайт-визитка). Зачастую это одностраничный сайт без привязки к СУБД. Реже - с формами обратной связи (оставьте почту/номер телефона и наш менеджер свяжется с вами). В качестве примера - https://sunbey13.github.io/PersTren/
На таких сайтах, как правило, предоставляется общая информация о компании/предоставляемых услугах, их примеры и расценки

Comment: Сколь будет стоить примерно такой сайт https://sunbey13.github.io/PersTren/ , и сколько времени уйдет на разработку

Comment: все зависит от того, за сколько вы сможете продать час своей работы и навыков. В моем конкретном случае это заняло день+-, но я за него ничего не выручил, т.к. это было задание по программе университета

Comment: @Akmal, а вообще, все зависит от кол-ва "экранов", страниц и прочего. Есть одна интересная таблица, которая можем вам помочь.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IdndaEhj5Q02khMIfVtFGAjWbfWulC-M4KCD4PLaXEs/edit#gid=0